# Servlets showing different outputs?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am using a simple servlet code:

```
        myCon = DriverManager.getConnection(url);


        myStmt = myCon.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs;

        String course = req.getParameter("Course").trim();

         out.println(course);///////HERE IS THE PROBLEM

        String query="select * from TBSolvedbanks where COURSE_CODE='"+course+"' ;";
        rs=myStmt.executeQuery(query);


        out.println("<BANKS>");

        while(rs.next())
        {
            out.println("<BANK>");
            out.println("<NUMBER>"+rs.getString("NUMBER")+"</NUMBER>");
            out.println("<NAME>"+rs.getString("NAME")+"</NAME>");
            out.println("<TITLE>"+rs.getString("TITLE")+"</TITLE>");
            out.println("<DESCRIPTION>"+rs.getString("DESCRIPTION")+"</DESCRIPTION>");
            out.println("<MODULE_TAG>"+rs.getString("MODULE_TAG")+"</MODULE_TAG>");
            out.println("<ADDITIONAL_TAGS>"+rs.getString("ADDITIONAL_TAGS")+"</ADDITIONAL_TAGS>");
            out.println("</BANK>");

        }
        out.println("</BANKS>"); 
    }
```

When I am running this code on Jboss server it works fine and prints this:

```
                BEME1104
                <BANKS>
                <BANK>
               <NUMBER>1</NUMBER>
               <NAME>firstbank</NAME>
               <TITLE>Question Bank 1</TITLE>
               <DESCRIPTION>in this file,we discussed basic things including shortnotes          of Properties of substances and aproaches</DESCRIPTION>
               <MODULE_TAG>MODULE I</MODULE_TAG>
               <ADDITIONAL_TAGS>Uses of point,path function,processes,equilibrium,curves</ADDITIONAL_TAGS>
               </BANK>
```

But when I comment this line

```
               out.println(course);
```

It prints the values without tags like this:

```
"1 firstbank Question Bank 1 in this file,we discussed basic things including shortnotes of Properties of substances and aproaches MODULE I Uses of point,path function,processes,equilibrium,curves"
```

I dont know why I am facing this problem while same code runs fine in another servlet.Please help me I am new to servlets?

Comment: Your code is open for SQL Injection Attacks and you should take caution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the page source in your browser. You're not setting the content-type of the response. So the browser probably displays the first one as plain text because it doesn't start with anything looking like HTML, and tries to displays the second one as HTML, but since it's not valid HTML, it doesn't look good.

If you want to always have the response displayed as plain text, add

```
response.setContentType("text/plain");
```

Answer (score -1):

@Navdeep Singh Bedi...

Use below code before while loop and try again....

PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();